# HttpResponse object has no attribute get_absolute_url

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, registration, httpresponse

So, I am trying to write my own registration back-end because I have to and I am running into some troubles.

I get:

> HttpResponse object has no attribute get_absolute_url

and have no idea how to fix this.

Here is my code:

```
class MyRegistrationBackend(object):

    def register(self, request, **kwargs):

        username, email, password = kwargs['username'], kwargs['email'], kwargs['password1']       

        encode_drupal = DrupalPasswordHasher()
        password = encode_drupal.create(str(password),"E","LOhihi6WNUA.")   #drupal style hasher
        print "sha512 pass: ", password
        #ask if user is already registered
        req = urllib2.Request(settings.DJANGO_SERVER+"/api/stats/customuser/"+username+"/?format=json",
            headers = {"Authorization": basic_authorization(settings.DJANGO_OAUTH_USERNAME, settings.DJANGO_OAUTH_PASSWORD),"Content-Type": "application/json"}
        )
        resp = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(req).read())
        print resp
        if resp['username']!='':
           #do something

        else:
                if resp['password'] != password: #password does not match received pass
                    print "wrong credentials"
                    return render_to_response('registration/error.html')
```

Traceback :

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://192.168.1.77:8000/accounts/register/

Django Version: 1.4.2
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'registration',
 'administration',
 'tastypie',
 'south',
 'social_auth',
 'django_extensions',
 'djcelery',
 'braces',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'youbeqadmin.middleware.crossdomainxhr.XsSharing')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/registration/views.py" in register
  189.                 to, args, kwargs = backend.post_registration_redirect(request, new_user)
File "/home/psychok7/git/mysite/mysite/backends.py" in post_registration_redirect
  126.         return (user.get_absolute_url(), (), {})

Exception Type: AttributeError at /accounts/register/
Exception Value: 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'get_absolute_url'
```

Any ideas? I believe it has something to do with:

> render_to_response

, but i dont know how to fix this.

UPDATE:

if I return None, I get:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_absolute_url'

Comment: Show full stacktrace. No fortunetellers here.

Comment: So, how did it happen that your `HttpResponse` object is called `user`? I hope you can clearly see that you haven't posted that part of code that is actually not working.

Comment: i based my code on some other persons code, and they return user. And in fact it also works for me. the rest of the code saves the user model and returns it and it works. except for this part

Comment: i need to somehow redirect the registration page to an error page because the password is not the same as the one i got from my remote server. i do this to prevent account hijacking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Django backend needs to either return a User object (or equivalent which would have `get_absolute_url`), or it needs to return `None` [(here's an example)](http://www.djangorocks.com/tutorials/creating-a-custom-authentication-backend/creating-a-simple-authentication-backend.html). Your authentication library should not be re-directing, that's your `view`s' job.

Comment: if i return None, i get a 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_absolute_url' also

Comment: redirecting and returning None are not the same thing. The backend should either return None or a valid User. The view should *test the returned value* and return the appropriate HttpResponse (a 'redirect' being a HttpResponse).

Comment: i haven't written any view for this i believe. i think i am using django-registration default view.. which one is the view where i can control this behaviour, or how can i somehow override its behaviour?

Comment: i figuered it out. i went here https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/2d6fcc0c55d0c63d5e506b59e32cad9329963509/registration/views.py?at=v0.8 and copied the register code and altered it to my own needs :)

Comment: but i did a copy paste of the register, isn't there a more beautiful way like extending it or so?